# How to fit a square view into a layout with rounded corners clipcorners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Here is my problem... I am trying to fit a square button into a layout that has rounded corners. See the screenshot below

[image: android-clip-corners]

The top section (Comment Section) is supposed to have rounded corners on the twitter and facebook share buttons to match the layout.

The bottom section (List View) is an example of how the shape is supposed to act.

Here is how I have my shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF747474" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Here is the Twitter share button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/iv_chat_detail_twittershare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:background="@drawable/sharetwitter" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy was to do this since the background of your linearlayout is still the full rectangle, despite it being set to a shape with rounded corners. One way to do accomplish this, and I admit it's a little overcomplicated, is to create individual selectors for the facebook and twitter buttons and set the appropriate corner radii.

```
<!-- facebook button corners -->
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/> 

<!-- twitter button corners -->
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```